# How to read data chunk wise into memory from the database?

Tags: c#, linq

Basically what am trying to accomplish is perform CRUD operations on a large amount of data in the database(using mvc 4 , LINQ)
i have a table here called messages.
i need to query it and retrieve those msgs with folderid = 10 (which is more than a million in number)

```
<List>Messages msgList = from msg in db.messages
                         where msg.folderid.equals(10)
                         select msg).tolist();
```

this will return me a million in the msgList collection.
I would like to retrieve records in chunks, say about 5000 at a time.
please help!

Answer (score 2):

The 2 other current answers (Kuruvilla & Ben) both have caveats which you may need to consider...

1) Using a flag means that you need to update this database to keep track of processed messages.. this may or may not be feasible.. but its not the only way

2) Using skip and take is a good idea if you are sure that no items are added between calls.. this is called paging and it may mean that the second page contains an item you have already processed if that happens!

If either of those points are concerns then I would recommend ordering your messages by Id, keeping track of the last id processed and using this in a where clause, in conjunction with Take:

```
var msgList = (from msg in db.messages
               order by msg.id
               where msg.id > lastProcessedId
               select msg).Take(5000).ToList();
```

Persist the lastProcessedId after each message processed, that way you can continue on where you left off if anything goes wrong

Comment: Yes indeed!, i guess ill make that lastProcessedId as a static variable in my data layer so that its count doesnt get lost between calls

Comment: I've used this technique before and if you have an auto-incrementing primary ID column it works very well

Comment: Actually , i do have the msg.id as auto incrementing! hopefully it should work

Answer (score 1):

You better have Flag after done something to first 5000 and update that flag of each record.
Now you can take another 5000 which not having above flag.

```
var msgList = (from msg in db.messages
                         where msg.folderid ==10 && msg.flag
                              select msg).Take(5000).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 This is the only sure way to mark each individual record *complete*.

Comment: Its best to avoid doing this if possible.. it creates coupling

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Skip` and `Take` to do this style of chunking.  Read about skip and take [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).  In your case, you probably want to wrap your query (which is in query syntax) in order to call these methods (which are only available in fluent syntax).  Make sure to use `Take` before the call to `ToList`, which is when the records are called into memory.  For the first 100 records, use:

```
var msgList = (from msg in db.messages
               where msg.folderid == 10
               select msg).Take(100).ToList();
```

And then for the next 100 records use:

```
var msgList = (from msg in db.messages
               where msg.folderid == 10
               select msg).Skip(100).Take(100).ToList();
```

Etc.

Comment: Thanks Ben, so i need to put take and skip in some sort of a loop.

Comment: Yeah that could work.  Keep track of where you are, skip that many records, and then take the next block in each iteration of the loop.  Of course, every time this executes, the query is re-evaluated, so if the records might be changing, make sure the query is doing what you want!